# set `outerHTML`, act like angular injector in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to write some thing just like angular injector and bind data in html node, it spouse to support `item.id` type to bind.

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.setAttribute('class', '{id}');

var data = { id: "ok" };

var result = injector(element, data);
var expect = '<div class="ok"></div>';
console.log(result + " == " + expect);

function injector(elem, data) {
    var content = elem.outerHTML;
    elem.outerHTML = content.replace(/({([\w|.]+)})/g, inject);
    return elem;
    function inject(match, offset, string) {
        return data[offset]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope some ideas I had will be a hint for you.
There are several ways to do this problem. You can manipulate the `outerHTML` string or the attriutes of the `HtmlElement` with `setAttribute`.

## Solutions

#### String Manipulation

*follows*

#### Change HtmlElement Object

```js
let element = document.createElement('div')
element.setAttribute('class', '{a}')
element.setAttribute('id', '{a}')
element.setAttribute('data-x', '{b}')

let data = {
  a: 'ok',
  b: 'okok'
}

injector(element, data)

console.log(
  `${element.outerHTML} === <div class="ok" id="ok" data-x="okok"></div>`,
  element.outerHTML === '<div class="ok" id="ok" data-x="okok"></div>'
)

function injector (htmlElement, data) {
  let allAttributes = getAllAttributes(htmlElement)
  let reduced = allAttributes.reduce((acc, currentAttribute) => {
    let currentAttributeValue = htmlElement
      .getAttribute(currentAttribute)
      .replace(/(\{)|(\})/g, '')
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(currentAttributeValue)) {
      acc[currentAttributeValue] = acc[currentAttributeValue].concat(currentAttribute)
    } else {
      acc[currentAttributeValue] = [currentAttribute]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
  Object.keys(reduced)
    .forEach(key => {
      reduced[key].forEach(attribute => {htmlElement.setAttribute(attribute, data[key])})
    })
}

function getAllAttributes (htmlElement) {
  let outerHtml = htmlElement.outerHTML
  let tagName = htmlElement.tagName
  let outerHtmlWithoutTagName = outerHtml.replace(
    new RegExp(tagName.toLowerCase(), 'g')
    , ''
  )
  return outerHtmlWithoutTagName.replace(
    /(="{([\w|.]+)}")|(\<|\>|\/)/g
    , ''
  )
    .trim()
    .split(' ')
}
```